# Losing <asp:Label> Text value from ViewState for dynamically added control

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, viewstate

I am adding controls to a page programatically in the code behind. I add an asp:Label and set it's Text value. I add an asp:TextBox and set it's Text value. Both Text values are returned in the Response and displayed in the browser. All fine so far.

The user performs an action that causes a postback. I re-load the dynamically added asp:Label and asp:TextBox. When the Response is returned to the browser, only the asp:TextBox Text value is displayed. The asp:Label Text value is not.

If I inspect the HTML I can see the asp:Label control (rendered as an HTML span tag) but no value.

How can I get the code to automatically re-load the Text value of an asp:Label on each postback? Why is the behaviour different for an asp:Label and an asp:TextBox? I do not want to have to manually re-set the Text value on each postback.

Here is some code similar to what I am doing (placeHolderNameplates is an asp:PlaceHolder control on the aspx page):

```
    Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim lbl As Label = New Label()
        lbl.ID = "xxx1"
        lbl.Text = "yo"
        placeHolderNameplates.Controls.Add(lbl)

        Dim tb As TextBox = New TextBox
        tb.ID = "xxx2"
        tb.Text = "yoyo"
        placeHolderNameplates.Controls.Add(tb)

    Else
        Dim lbl As Label = New Label()
        lbl.ID = "xxx1"
        placeHolderNameplates.Controls.Add(lbl)

        Dim tb As TextBox = New TextBox
        tb.ID = "xxx2"
        placeHolderNameplates.Controls.Add(tb)

    End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is add the control to the placeholder before setting the values, so it should be 
`Dim lbl As Label = New Label()

placeHolderNameplates.Controls.Add(lbl)

lbl.ID = "xxx1"

lbl.Text = "yo"`

See these posts for details:
http://www.yakkowarner.com/2008/01/aspnet-dynamic-controls-and-viewstate.html
http://codebetter.com/jefferypalermo/2004/11/25/key-to-ensuring-dynamic-asp-net-controls-save-viewstate-level-300/

> Before they are added to the page, they have not initialized themselves.  When a dynamic control is added to another control, the new control plays catch-up to get to the stage that the parent control is in.  For instance, if in your Page_Load, you add a textbox, it will play catch-up and go through its Init and Load phases.  This is important beceause it will start tracking its viewstate.  Values added before it is tracking viewstate won’t make it to viewstate and will be lost on PostBack.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like dynamically created controls won't be added to the ViewState automatically. The TextBox Control retains it's value however because of it's nature of being rendered to a `<input type="text" value="xyz" />` html element.

Have a look at this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3684/Retaining-State-for-Dynamically-Created-Controls-i

Answer (score 0):

Hey check thsi site MSDN

You have to add your control with following event( so viewstate maintain automaticly)

```
override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
```

example of Add Dynamic control 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317794/en-us